# Why is it valid to set $r=e^t$ in $f(r)=\frac{r+r^{-1}}{2}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

$f(r)=\frac{r+r^{-1}}{2}$

$f(re^{i \theta})=\frac{re^{i\theta}+r^{-1}e^{-i\theta}}{2}=\frac{r+r^{-1}}{2}\cos\theta+i\frac{r-r^{-1}}{2}\sin\theta$

Why is it then valid to set $r=e^t$, $-\infty≤t≤0$

in order to find

$f(re^{i\theta})=\cosh(t)\cos(\theta)+i\sinh(t)\sin(\theta)$

---

This is from:

http://people.reed.edu/~jerry/311/lec04.pdf, p.3.

Comment: If $r$ is positive then there exists a unique $t$ such that $r=e^t$... this $t=\ln r$.

Comment: @JpMcCarthy Yes, but why does this cover the entire domain of $r$. This leads to claim that all $z$ such that $|z|=r$ are mapped into ellipses.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* Due to the symmetry property of $f$ the focus of the function  was put to the punctured disc $\overline{D}^\circ=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:0<|z|\leq 1\}$. Within this disc the modulus $r$ of a point $z=re^{i\theta}$ can be set to

\begin{align*}r=e^{t} \qquad\qquad -\infty<t\leq 0\tag{1}
\end{align*}

If we consider the function $f:\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ with
\begin{align*}
f(z)=\frac{z+z^{-1}}{2}
\end{align*}
we have $f(\frac{1}{z})=f(z)$. On the other hand note that $z\rightarrow \frac{1}{z}$ maps a point $z=re^{i\theta}$ *outside* of the punctured disc  $\overline{D}^\circ$ to a point $\frac{1}{z}=\frac{1}{r}e^{-i\theta}$ *inside* the disc and vice versa. Due to this bijection it is sufficient to consider the points inside the disc, which is realized by the condition (1). We so get
\begin{align*}
f\left(re^{i\theta}\right)=\frac{r+r^{-1}}{2}\cos\theta+i\frac{r-r^{-1}}{2}\sin\theta=f\left(\frac{1}{r}e^{-i\theta}\right)
\end{align*}
which describes a relationship for points inside the disc as well as for corresponding  points outside the disc.

Comment: We haven't covered that kind of property yet. In complex analysis.

Comment: @mavavilj: I mean the property at the beginning of the paragraph at p.3 in the paper which states that $f(z^{-1})=f(z)$.

Comment: Yeah, but we haven't covered that/why it means that one can "move the analysis into the disc".

Comment: @mavavilj: I have my answer somewhat extended which might be helpful.